# Allocating memory to a struct using pointers

Tags: c, list, struct

I have the following linked list:

```
struct node {
    int d;
    struct node *next;   
};

int main()
{
    struct node *l = 0;
    struct node *k = l;
    k = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    /* l->d = 8; */
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the commented code wrong to use? I don't understand why the memory isn't allocated for the node that ``l points to since `k` points to the same node as `l` and I used the `k`-pointer to allocate memory for it.

Comment: Your concepts doesn't seems to be clear, I would suggest you to watch some video lectures and clarify your concepts about dynamic memory allocation using malloc() or others and linked lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take it apart. Look at the comments

```
struct node{
    int d;
    struct node * next;   
};

int main(){
    struct node * l = 0;     // Now l = 0 (or NULL)
    struct node * k = l;     // Now k=l=0
    k = malloc(sizeof(struct node));   // Now k=<some address allocated>
    /*
    l->d = 8;                          // But l is still 0
    */
    return 0;
}
```

So the commented code is trying to dereference a NULL pointer.

Comment: What I don't understand: aren't both k and l pointers ? So if both point to the same location, wouldn't changing k or allocating memory to the same location result in l pointing to the same location with allocated memory ?

Comment: At the first hand both `k` and `l` are **variables**. If you are assigning them a value, they will retain it unless you reassign it either directly, or by **dereferencing a pointer to them**, not the pointer having the same value.

Comment: @Eugene_Sh. Am I understanding it correctly: struct node *l is a variable and struct node *pl is a pointer to a struct node whereas int *p; is a pointer to an int ?

Comment: Both `l` and `pl` have the same type, which is pointer to `node`. `p` is a pointer to `int`. But a `pointer to <type>` is a type itself, so having an identifier of type `pointer to <type>` is making it variable of that type.